# How to disable magit-revision buffer from following the cursor in blame buffers?

Tags: magit

Open a file in a git repo that is modified by two commits.  Run `magit-blame`.

```
*author1 date1 commit1*
line1
*author2 date2 commit2*
line 2
```

Focus on the first line, press `Enter`.  A `magit-revision` buffer opens at `commit1`.

Go back to the main file, go to the next line.  The `magit-revision` buffer now displays `commit2`.

How do I disable this behavior?  I'd like the revision buffer to stay at `commit1` until I explicitly ask it to switch - e.g. by pressing `Enter` on `line2`.

Answer (score 1):

Customize variable `magit-blame-goto-chunk-hook` and remove the following function from the list: `magit-blame-maybe-update-revision-buffer`.

Comment: Note to mods: the question asker is me at the previous job, so the account is no longer active and cannot accept the answer.  The question-answer pair stays for posterity.